# Form validation model override not working

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

I need to validate a data entry looking to another table in the DB, so Im trying to override the validate_form function but by know, it's seems like the function run once I click on create in that view.

```
def validate_form(self, form):
    stock = db.session.query(Inventory.in_stock).filter(Inventory.product_id==form.product.raw_data[0]).filter(Inventory.use_for==form.tag.raw_data[0]).scalar()
    if stock < form.quantity.data:
        flash("Quantity is greater than stock for this Item!")
        return False
    return super(OutView, self).validate_form(form)
```

The error that appears once I click on create is:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

And it cames from form.product due it's empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add full stack trace and how you define the form that you validate, it's hard to suggest anything without it.

Comment: Is the default creation form that came with flask-admin ModelView, I didnt edit anything.